# Linux版AndroidStudioでadb SyntaxErorrが出る

Tags: android, linux, android-studio, ubuntu

エミュレーターを実行しようとすると、

> adb Syntax error: ")" unexpected

と出ます。platform-toolsが原因でしょうか。また、対処法は何でしょう。環境はUbuntu 32bitです

Comment: 使用しているplatform-toolsのバージョンはいくつですか？

Comment: 最新のr24.4.1です。前のバージョンでは出てなかったりしますか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[android studio adb Syntax error: “)” unexpected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34216342/android-studio-adb-syntax-error-unexpected)や   [Platform-tools 23.1.0 Linux changed to 64-bit without notice.](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=196866)で議論されているように、どうやら platform-tools 23.1.0 からは 64-bit 版の Linux でなければ動作をしなくなったようです。

実際、[Android Studio と SDK Tools のダウンロード#システム要件](http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/sdk/index.html#Requirements)にも

```
Ubuntu® 14.04、Trusty Tahr（32-bit 版アプリケーションを実行可能な 64-bit 版）でテスト済み。
```

と書かれています。

そのため、開発環境を64-bitの Ubuntu へ変更をするか、または 23.1.0 未満の platform-tools で開発をする必要があると思います。